# Using HighCharts styledMode in Angular 8 application

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am working on an Angular 8 application using highcharts-angular v2.4.0 and highcharts v7.1.2

I have set the chart styledMode to true in my typescript chartOptions and I have placed the following in the components scss file

```css
.highcharts-pie-series.highcharts-legend-item.highcharts-color-0 {
    text {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
}
```

I have read the articles on Highcharts about apply a theme or overriding styles, but nothing I try has any affect on the resulting pie graph or legend. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when using style mode you have to add styles globally.

Inside `angular-cli.json` add CSS file for the chart styles (chart-styles.css and theme.css below):

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": ["assets", "favicon.ico"],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": ["styles.css", "theme.css", "chart-styles.css"],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/cqxuh